# error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Platform' does not exist in the namespace 'Xamarin.Essentials'

Tags: .net, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.essentials

When updating to Xamarin.Essentials v1.8.0, my Android builds fail with the following error:

```bash
error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Platform' does not exist in the namespace 'Xamarin.Essentials'
```

I checked the [Xamarin.Essentials source code and confirmed that the `Xamarin.Essentials.Platform` class](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/blob/d521376076143b1842cf046061dd5c8ba80eb5b3/Xamarin.Essentials/Platform/Platform.android.cs) does still exist.

The only thing I've changed is to update the Xamarin.Essentials NuGet package from v1.7.7 to v1.8.0. It's not a major release, so there shouldn't be any breaking changes to my app. Is there something wrong with this build / release of Xamarin.Essentials?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Explanation

In the [Release Notes for Xamarin.Essentials v1.8.0](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/releases/tag/1.8.0), they mention that it is now targeting Android 33:

> Target MonoAndroid13.0 by @jfversluis in [#2087](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/pull/2087)

#### Solution

This means that to use Xamarin.Essentials, you now need to be targeting Android API 33 in your Xamarin.Android app, and there are two files we must update to fix this:

##### Xamarin.Android CSPROJ

In the `csproj` file for your Anrdoid app (typically named `*.Droid.csproj` or `*.Android.csproj`), update the `<TargetFrameworkVersion>` to `v13.0`:

```xml
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v13.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

#### AndroidManifest.xml

In `AndroidManifest.xml` (aka The Android Manifest), update `android:targetSdkVersion` to `"33"`:

```xml
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="33" />
```

Comment: It works for 1.8.0, but somehow does not work for 1.8.1.

Comment: The Release notes for v1.8.1 show they've added Android 34 support. Increase your targetSdkVersion to "34" Add API 34/Android 14. https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/releases/tag/1.8.1